# How is opsin of rhodopsin is different from that of iodopsin?

Tags: proteins, eyes, human-eye, protein-structure

Rhodopsin contain retinal, an aldehyde of vitamin A and opsin protein and iodopsin also contains retinal along three different types of opsins namely erythropsin, chloropsin and cyanopsin. But kind of opsin does rhodopsin has ?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean to ask.

Comment: What I want to ask is, like in iodopsin, there are three different types of opsin protein erythropsin, chloropsin and cyanopsin. But in rhodopsin we have retinal and opsin but how is this opsin different from the opsins of iodopsin ?

Comment: Different *how*? What sort of differences are you looking for?

Comment: See, rhodopsin consists of retinal and opsin which on separation of which we are able to perceive light. Now in case of iodopsin which is found is cones also contains retinal and three different kinds of opsins namely chloropsin, erythropsin and cyanopsin. Now the opsin that we find in rhodopsin, how is it different from these chloropsin, erythropsin and cyanopsin that are found in iodopsin ?

Comment: How is it different *how*? Imagine you have cats and dogs and you want to know how they are different. The list would be endless: you could talk about how they make different sounds, have different diets, their color, the texture of their fur, their history of domestication, etc. Which characteristic of these opsins are you asking for a comparison of?

Comment: I'm asking how they're chemically different ?

Comment: They're different proteins; they have different amino acids. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Yes, what kind of groups they have in their structure ?

Comment: What do you mean by "groups"? What are you trying to learn or do?

Comment: I'm talking about functional groups such -CHO, -OH, -CO- etc that we usually find in organic compounds.

Comment: There are a few hundred amino acids in an opsin protein; each are going to have one or more of those functional groups in addition to the amino backbone.